# How to fetch set of 10 records each time for multiple keys in DynamoDB using BatchGetItem?

Tags: indexing, amazon-dynamodb

UseCase: I am getting multiple requests from the different clients. So, I need to store these requests in a database (preferably DynamoDB), sort them up in order of incoming time, and fetch sets of 10 for all the clients at one moment.

For example: If there are 5 clients: C1, C2, C3, C4, C5 and all are sending 50 requests at one point of time, which I store them in DB with their timestamp. Now I need to fetch only 10 requests objects from all the clients in order of timestamp rather than fetching all of them. So, the request which came in first, needs to be processed first.

How can I implement this using DynamoDB GSI and the BatchGetItem API ?
Or is there some other way in which this can be implemented?

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect use case for SQS FIFO queues. It seems like your best option.

If you really must do it with DynamoDB you aren't going to be using `BatchGetItem`, you'll be using `Query`. `BatchGetItem` is for retrieving multiple items in one request **when you know the keys of the records you want**. With a query you specify a partition key and optionally a sort key, or a function for the sort key. The biggest issue you'll have with using DynamoDB is that you need to make sure you only get the record once, so you'll have to do something to either remove the record or update the record in a way that doesn't get queried again. This is all doable, but again, SQS is more suited for this.

Comment: are you suggesting multiple SQS queues for multiple clients? In that thing, I would have to create a new SQS queue whenever a new client comes for on-boarding to the server.